# class template pointer type destructor error visual studio 2015 v140

Tags: c++, class, pointers, templates, operator-overloading

I want to implement a generic data structure using a class template with pointer types.
When i want to use the operator+ program gives "Access violation reading location" error (which is given below). The minimum working code is given.

This is the main definition

```
template <class T>
class Data
{
  public:
     Data() {}  
     ~Data() {}

  public:
  T m_value;
};

//This is the specialization for pointer types
template <class T>
class Data<T*>
{
 public:
    Data()  { m_value = new T();} 
    //~Data() {delete m_value;}   ********This gives error***
    ~Data() {}                   //****** This works 

    Data(const T value)  { m_value = new T(value); }

    template <class T>
    friend Data<T*> operator+(Data<T*> a, Data<T*> b);

    Data<T*>& operator=(const Data<T*> value);

 public:
    T* m_value;
};


//friend operator+
template <class T>
Data<T*> operator+(Data<T*> a, Data<T*> b)
{ 
    Data<T*> temp(*a.m_value + *b.m_value);
    return temp;
}

//member operator=
template <class T>
Data<T*>& Data<T*>::operator=(const Data<T*> value)
{
    if (!this->m_value)
        this->m_value = new T();

    *this->m_value = *value.m_value;
    return *this;
}
```

Error on the line : operator+ (which calls destructor above)

```
void main()    
{
    typedef Data<int *> Data_Int;

    Data_Int dt1(100);
    Data_Int dt2(200);
    Data_Int dt3;

    dt3 = dt1 + dt2; // error line              

}
```

Error occurs at operator delete

```
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK); //Error line 
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

error output

```
Exception thrown at 0x5CF33B8D (ucrtbased.dll) in Deneme.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x006E0069.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: “This gives error“ - which error?

Comment: Sorry @S.M, I edit the question

Comment: Please include the *full* and *complete*  error output, copy-pasted. And also enable verbose warning when building.

Comment: You violated the rule of three. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: I edit the question again @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: sorry for the missing parts @S.M.

Comment: There's another problem with your code which I'd fix: `T` suggests it is a macro, because it is all uppercase. I seem to remember seeing a `T()` macro on some Windows compilers, so that could cause additional portability problems. Also, extracting a [mcve] could have shown you that the whole `template` stuff is actually not necessary. That's one of the reasons the MCVE is an actual requirement.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: I enabled verbose warning after you suggest , but couldn't see  any additional warnings @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately i realized that it was a simple error. The proper copy constructor was missing, so the compiler naturally made an implicit one and made pointer to pointer assignment which is the source of the error.

So the correct copy constructor for the above code is

```
Data(const Data<T*> & copy) { data_ptr = new T(*copy.data_ptr); }
```